# Elmah MySql Nuget Package Issue 'Could not load file or assembly'

Tags: c#, mysql, nuget, elmah

I'm trying to add Elmah to my MVC3 project.  After installing via Nuget, when I try to access elmah (via `localhost:port/elmah.axd`), I get an error containing this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've removed the mysql.data dll and added my own copy (version 6.4.4.0 - the documentation says you can override the dll provided with a newer version), but this error remains.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was to add this to my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity 
          name="MySql.Data" 
          publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" 
          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.4.4.0" newVersion="6.4.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This basically says to the compiler that whenever something requests a version of the `MySql.Data` assembly that's between versions 0.0.0.0 and 6.4.4.0, it should instead be supplied with the version 6.4.4.0 assembly instead.